# Unable to apply background style on button in Android

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to apply background style on button for that I created a drawable resource file but it's unable to take its effect. It's only showing white button only.

Below is my code:

**log_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle">

<solid
    android:color="@color/accent"/>

<corners
    android:radius="10dp"/>

</shape>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="LOGOUT"
    android:background="@drawable/log_out"/>
```

How can I achieve the desired layout?

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the application theme. This structure will not work if you are using a Material Design theme.

If you change the main theme with `parent = "Theme.AppCompat.DayNight"` as an example, it will work.

Comment: Then how can I make this with Material Design theme.

Comment: app:backgroundTint used and MaterialButton